# Scaling big values

Tags: c#, double

I've created simple WPF control to draw charts in my application. Now I need to draw a f(x) = 2^x function on it. All values (from specified range) must be visible on the chart - they should be scaled so that f(x) value for maxX will be on right top corner. Unfortunately, x can have big values, i.e. 1000. Math.Pow() returns infinity for big values.

The solution I see is to manually calculate Math.Pow() value - on each step I will divide all previous values instead of multiplying maximum by 2 (I don't really need f(x) value itself). But maybe you'll find a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you know the maximum value, it's `2 ** max_x`.  So normalize all values by this:

```
y_norm = y / 2 ** max_x
       = 2 ** x * 2 ** -max_x
       = 2 ** (x - max_x)
```

Comment: The problem is that max_x (or x - max_x) can be i.e. 1000. I can't simply calculate 2^1000.

Comment: @Marcin: Either you use a log plot, in which case you calculate `(x - max_x) * lg 2`, or else you're calculating `2 ** -1000`, which rounds to zero, which is fine because your display has far less precision than your floating-point numbers.  (although `2**1000` and `2**-1000` actually are representable with double precision floating-point).

Comment: Yes, I can get `2^1000` as double but `2^2000` not. Lets say that I have 2 x values - 999 and 1000. In that case I will have `2^1000` on the right top corner and `2^999` on bottom left. There are only `2^1` times difference between values, but it could also be `2^1000` or more. I can't assume that difference will be so small that I can calculate it, and that it'll be so big that I can not draw smaller values.

Comment: @Marcin: What do expect to happen when you draw smaller values?  Having them round off to zero just doesn't matter in this scenario, unless your screen is more than 2**1000 pixels in height.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood you :) Everything seems to work fine and I see almost vertical line on my chart. Thx :D